# SQL: UPDATE query which doesn't affect timestamp on the row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, row

I have some SQL code below which enables me to change all instances of quantities that are '0' and change them to '1' within the 'quantity' column only. It works ok but...

What I am trying to do, however, is not affect the timestamp column (called 'entry_date') on the affected rows ie. keep the original time the entry was made. When I run this query it replaces the time the entry was originally made with the time the query below was ran.

How do I get around this? I have basic-intermediate PHP knowledge but my SQL knowledge isn't great. Any help would be appreciated.

> UPDATE `databasename`.`tablename` SET `quantity` = '1'
>   WHERE `tablename`.`quantity` = '0';

Answer (score 1):

First, `DESCRIBE tablename`, and note "entry_date" has *Extra* info "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".  That's the behavior you want to avoid.

Next, `ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN entry_date TIMESTAMP [NULL | NOT NULL] DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

(You specify 'NULL' or 'NOT NULL' as appropriate.)

Finally, `DESCRIBE tablename` again, and note that the *Extra* info is gone.

Comment: (and add either `NULL` or `NOT NULL` in the `MODIFY COLUMN` clause, to keep the column's nullability).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
UPDATE databasename.tablename SET quantity = '1', entry_date = entry_date
WHERE tablename.quantity = '0';
```

and see if it doesn't override the behaviour specified by the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want timestamp field `entry_date` to not change automatically on update.. you need following query to execute before any update query on your table

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` CHANGE `entry_date` `entry_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
 DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Opposite : After this if you again want timestamp field `entry_date` to change automatically on update.. you need following query to execute before any update query on your table

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` CHANGE `entry_date` `entry_date` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```